# Rails: Update model attribute without invoking callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, attributes, callback

I have a User model that has a :credits attribute.   I want a simple button that will add 5 to  the user's credits, through a route called "add" so that /users/3/add would add 5 to the credits of user id = 3.

```
def add
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.credits += 5
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

That is the relevant part of my controller.  The problem is, I dont want to call @user.save because I have a before_save callback that re-encrypts the user's password based on the current UTC time.   I just want to simply add 5 to the attribute and avoid the callback, I never thought such a simple thing could be so hard.

EDIT:

I changed the callback to :before_create,
here is my new controller code (relevant part):

```
  def add
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.add_credits(5)
    @user.save
    flash[:success] = "Credits added!"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

and here is my code in the model:

```
 def add_credits(num)
    self.credits = num
 end
```

EDIT 2:

Ok it was a validation problem that made the changes in "EDIT" not work, but I'd still love an answer to the original question of updating without callbacks!

Comment: I provided a link with a list of the methods that don't trigger callbacks, and both Finbarr and I suggested using a conditional callback--what additional solutions are you looking for?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Rails 3.1 introduced `update_column`, which is the same as `update_attribute`, but without triggering validations or callbacks:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column

Comment: I would love to use this but I can't upgrade to Rails 3.1 cleanly, or at least I don't know how.

Comment: Which Rails version are you running at the moment?

Answer (score 35):

As a general answer, in Rails 4 this is a simple way to update attributes without triggering callbacks:

```
@user.update_column :credits, 5
```

If you need to update multiple attributes without triggering callbacks:

```
@user.update_columns credits: 5, bankrupt: false
```

There are other options [here in the Rails Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks) if you prefer, but I found this way to be the easiest.

Comment: user.update_column credits:5

 does not work. It should be

user.update_column 'credits', 5

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.2 and this definitely works for me. This line generates the following query: `UPDATE "users" SET "credits" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["credits", 5], ["updated_at", "2017-04-01 21:34:52.746626"], ["id", 1]]`

Comment: When using `update_column`, you can't pass it an Object like `credits: 5`. You have to pass two parameters, the first being the column name and the second being the value to update it to. So you can do `update_column :credits, 5`, which would generally be preferred over using a String for the column name.

Answer (score 8):

To update multiple attributes without callbacks you can use update_all in your model as so:

```
self.class.update_all({name: value, name: value}, self.class.primary_key => id)
```

If you really want you can even try even a update_columns method and mixin this to your active record base class.

To update one attribute you can use update_column.  In addition there is some specific methods that can found in the rails guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks

Answer (score 8):

For mongoid, I ended up using http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/persistence.html
Specifically, you can use:

```
person.set(name:"Robert Pulson")
```

and no callback will be issued. So cool.

Comment: its person.set(:name, "Robert Pulson")

Comment: @JudeCalimbas no it's not, ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use the method [update_counters](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_counters/class) in this case. Use it like this in your controller action:

```
def add
  User.update_counters params[:id], :credits => 5
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) to avoid triggering callbacks.

```
def add
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 User.where(:id=>@user.id).update_all(:credits => @user.credits+5)
 redirect_to root_path
end
```

I'd prefer to put this logic in the model, but this should work to solve your original problem as spec'd in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of options, including changing which callback you use, e.g., `after_create`.

You can update columns without triggering callbacks, see [Skipping Callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks) in the AR guide. For example, `update_column` doesn't trigger callbacks. The previous link lists non-triggering functions.

You could also use any of the [Conditional Callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#conditional-callbacks) forms (or even an observer) for when the password is changed. See [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html), e.g., `@user.password_changed?`.

Comment: Ok I changed it to "after_create" but it still won't work!  See my edit for my new code, I can't get credits to change.

Comment: @hatboysam Well, it does something different--before you were adding, now you're setting. Use `save!` to see if there's an exception (and/or check the logs, and/or remove the backtrace silencers).

Answer (score 2):

A few options for how to do this in rails4 http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your other before_save hook should check if the user's password has actually changed before encrypting it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can update a column doing this

> User.where( name: 'lily' ).update_all(age: '10')